# Open the same folder in two different windows in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to open the same folder in two different windows. I opened the folder in the first window, but when I tried to open the folder in the second window, VS Code just jumped to the first window, instead of opening it in the second window.

I want to do this because I want to divide my files into two windows and I am using VSCoq, which requires VS Code to open a particular folder to work.

Comment: For your information, `code --new-window .` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me in VS Code 1.66.2

https://www.ryanchapin.com/running-multiple-vscode-windows-from-the-same-workspace/

```
CTRL+SHIFT+P
```

Then type

```
Workspaces: Duplicate As Workspace in New Window
```

---

As of VSCode 1.85, dragging tabs outside of the VSCODE window will create a new window in the same workspace

Answer (score 0):

open your folder as Workspace inside the new Window

```
CTRL+SHIFT+P

Workspaces: Duplicate As Workspace in New Window
```